# How can you make date formatter in Swift to show only the year part of the date?

Tags: swift, xcode, date, dateformatter

this is part of a project's code I came across:

```
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = .short
```

Other styles are ".full, .long, .medium, .short, .none" which neither is capable of showing only the year part of the date.

Thank you very much and have a wonderful day.

Comment: Just use `dateFormat = "yyyy"` instead of `dateStyle`. Another options is to use Calendar method `component(.year, from: date)` if you need its value instead of just the string representation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If you need to define a format that cannot be achieved using the predefined styles, you can use the `setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate(_:)` to specify a localized date format from a template.
>
> Source: [DateFormatter - Foundation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter)

In your case:

```
dateFormatter.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("yyyy")
```